# updating dictionary, saved in a plist

Tags: plist, ios5, nsdictionary

It doesn't work, if I try to add a new entry to my dictionary (plist). Editing is no problem. I think the problem is, how I try to add the entry.

If I remove the lines starting with "setObject", it returns YES.

my code looks like:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *updateDict = [[self.plist objectForKey:@"comments"]mutableCopy];

 NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init]autorelease];  
 [tmpDict setObject:comment forKey:@"comment"];
 [tmpDict setObject:author forKey:@"author"];
 [tmpDict setObject:car forKey:@"car"];
 [tmpDict setObject:part forKey:@"part"];
 [tmpDict setObject:date forKey:@"date"];

 [updateDict setObject:tmpDict forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[updateDict count]+1]];

 [self.plist setObject:updateDict forKey:@"comments"];
 if([self.plist writeToFile:self.plistPath atomically:YES]) {
return YES;
 }
 else {
     return NO;
 }
```

self.plist is my local copy of the file at plistPath. the structure of my plist looks like:

[image: https://img.skitch.com/20111026-tcjxp9ha4up8ggtfjy7ucgqcqe.png]

I'm developing for iOS 5.0 on the iPad.

hope this helps